# AngularJS Render HTML in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to render HTML values in text area SUBMIT FORM.
I can bind the html values in a `<div>` but not in a `<textarea>`.
Also, `ng-model` for data binding can retrieve the value but it is displayed as html.

Controller

```
//task.descr contains "<br>-------<br><a href="http://www.google.com"..."
var str="<br><hr><br>"+ task.descr;
//str= $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
$scope.formData5 = {
    descr: str}
console.log($scope.formData5);


<textarea placeholder="Deskripsi Memo"  name="descr" 
ngMaxlength="1000" ng-model="formData5.descr" 
ng-bind-html="formData5.descr" > </textarea>
```

Comment: Can't markup in textarea

Comment: if not using text area,what is the best way to render the HTML values as well as for ng-model?

Comment: use contenteditable for the div and achieve the same result :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would allow you have both two way data binding as well as give you the functionality of textarea:

```
  <div ng-bind-html="modelname"
         contenteditable="true"
         ng-model="modelname">
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pitura/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: I think content editable is a special directive. Please refer to: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html

Comment: Two way data binding doesn't work. Add `<p>{{inputText}}</p>` and check