# New line issue in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in AngularJS. In the form I have a field named "description".
If user enters description as:

> This is description:
>
> 1)point 1
>
> 2)point 2

I am saving this as :

```
"This is description:<br/>1)point 1 <br/> 2)point 2"
```

Now after saving it,to show it on page I am using something like :

```
 <span class="summary"><em ng-bind-html="(x.DES)"></em></span>
```

This code is working.

If users click on the record then I am loading the form in edit mode :

the form having the line in edit mode to show the description:

```
 <textarea  ng-focus="onFocusDescrption()" maxlength="600" name="cepDes" class="form-control" rows="3" cols="16"  ng-model="description" ng-disabled="isDescDisable" placeholder="Enter a description ..." id="description"></textarea>
```

Now the problem comes here. In controller I am setting the model value as :

```
$scope.description = $scope.timeEntry.DES;
```

Where in `$scope.timeEntry.DES` is having the value which is saved. The value is displayed in textarea having `<br>`.

Comment: It seems you have both ng-model="description" and ng-bind-html="(description)". You should only need ng-bind-html, and not ng-model. Also, your example is missing the n, in ng-bind-html.

Comment: Yes I am using ng-model in edit mode.I have edit the same

Comment: I was mistaking, you can't actually use markup in a textarea. I've created an answer which offers a solution.

Comment: One more issue is there is user type '\' in then json.stringify() convert it to '\\'

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to use markup in a textarea as you can see in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PdumLTzxO2WTmL9Fn4WH?p=preview) I have created, and more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911256/angularjs-render-html-in-textarea). A solution would be to use a directive which allows for editable content. This way you can use a div for displaying and editing:

```
<div ng-bind-html="modelname"
         contenteditable="true"
         ng-model="modelname">
</div>
```

The directive (also [on github](https://github.com/fdietz/recipes-with-angular-js-examples/tree/master/chapter8/recipe6)):

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
      }

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code you provide above.Yes it's working.Using div instead of textarea.

Comment: In the plunkr if I use :                                                        $scope.ngModelVar = "This is description:\n1)point 1 \n 2)point 2";
$scope.ngBindHtmlVar = "This is description:\n1)point 1 \n 2)point 2"; Then it's working.